# Limit the number of file Upload Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to limit the number of files upload against a role in wordpress. Is there any code or plugin available to do the job.

Any kind of solution will be entertained.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a plugin that does that stuff, but you can look at wp-admin/upload.php file to set your role-based limits there.

Yet, you won't be able to control the flash uploader from that file.

Comment: I want to know about that plugin please I dont want to modify the core files.......

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15264/media-upload-choose-only-one-file/15631#15631 - this is as close as I can get to the solution. I couldn't find a plugin for that - it's just reconfiguring the flash uploader.